# Cloudfront with Application Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-application-load-balancer

I have used AWS application load balancer for my domain and it is serving properly. However, I want to add caching layer for my website, but when I try to use Cloudfront for the same it gives me [502 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zPoa.png). I have followed aws blogs but unable to resolve the issue.
please find attached images for my cloudfront distribution.
[image: image1]
[image: image2][image: image3]

Comment: Did you setup ssl on your alb that you use https only?

Comment: I have setup ssl from ACM. and that works on both http & https.

Comment: Are you using internal or external ALB? Internal ALBs are not accessible from cloudfront

Comment: internet facing ALB.

Comment: Does your website work if you use alb url only?

Comment: yeah with only ALB it works fine.

Comment: Is your ALB open to the Internet (e.g. port 443 is open to `0.0.0.0/0`)?

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the similar problem before; to resolve it, I changed the origin's TLS from TLS1 to TLS1.2 and moved from http to https.